# Probability of a dot in a square to have larger distance from sides compared to distance with diameter

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We have a square. The length of a side is 1. We pick a random dot on it.
Should find the probability that of the distance between that dotes and the side lines of a square is smaller than the distance between the dot and the diameters of that square.

I tried to view it geometrically and found no matching case. Is the probability 0?
Or is this a NULL event?

Comment: It's not a null event: imagine the dot very near the midpoint of  side (in some epsilon nbhd of it). That dot will be far from the diameter, so closer to the side.

Comment: Thanks, does the problem want to just to discuss only 2 side lines? I tried to calculate the distance from all 4 sides @coffeemath

Comment: Referring to the distance "to the sides" means minimal of the four side distances. But I don't know what the wording of the problem means, makes a difference plural or not... Another issue is whether one or both diagonals is meant.

Comment: That is the thing that confuses me to be honest. But I'll try to calculate with minimal length. Thanks @coffeemath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the four  isosceles  triangles made on each side of the sqaure pointing towards the center of the square with the base angles of $22.5$ degrees.

The point should be inside one of these triangles to have its distance from the sides smaller than the distance from the diameters.

The total area of these triangles is $$\tan 22.5 \approx  0.41421$$

Thus the probability is about $0.41421$